# Remove double quotes from list of list elements in python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and I want to remove inside double quotes from each line.

Initially it was like this:

> [['"MILK,BREAD,BISCUIT"'], ['"BREAD,MILK,BISCUIT,CORNFLAKES"']]

After fixing my code I got this:

> [['"MILK', 'BREAD', 'BISCUIT"'], ['"BREAD', 'MILK', 'BISCUIT', 'CORNFLAKES"']]

I want to have like this

> [['MILK', 'BREAD', 'BISCUIT'], ['BREAD', 'MILK', 'BISCUIT', 'CORNFLAKES']]

I tried my best but I am not able to figure out how to do it.

My code looks like this:

```
def getFeatureData(featureFile):
x=[]
dFile = open(featureFile, 'r')
for line in dFile:
    row = line.split()
    #row[-1]=row[-1].strip()
    x.append(row)
dFile.close()
print(x)
return x
```

Comment: Your best bet is to go back to the program that wrote out these lists (which I'm guessing you wrote as well), and fix it so that it does not dump out all these quotes, commas and brackets.

Comment: Where does the data come from, how does it end up like this in the first place? The formatting of the code in your post looks broken. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: I don't Wana hard code my program I Wana keep my code dynamics so who ever Wana reuse my program they can do it by simply running on which ever file they wants to test in, more over I am passing sys level arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace and list comprehension.

```
list_with_quotes = [['"MILK,BREAD,BISCUIT"'], ['"BREAD,MILK,BISCUIT,CORNFLAKES"']]
list_without_quotes = [[l[0].replace('"','')] for l in list_with_quotes]
print(list_without_quotes)
>>out
>>[['MILK,BREAD,BISCUIT'], ['BREAD,MILK,BISCUIT,CORNFLAKES']]
```

EDIT sorry I did it quickly and didn't notice that my output is not exactly what you wanted. Here below a for loop that do the job:

```
list_without_quotes = []
for l in list_with_quotes:
    # get list
    with_quotes = l[0]
    # separate words by adding spaces before and after comma to use split
    separated_words = with_quotes.replace(","," ")
    # remove quotes in each word and recreate list
    words = [ w.replace('"','') for w in separated_words.split()]
    # append list to final list
    list_without_quotes.append(words)
print(list_without_quotes)
>>out
>>[['MILK', 'BREAD', 'BISCUIT'], ['BREAD', 'MILK', 'BISCUIT', 'CORNFLAKES']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using a list comprehension:

```
initial = [['"MILK,BREAD,BISCUIT"'], ['"BREAD,MILK,BISCUIT,CORNFLAKES"']]

final = [item[0].replace('"', '').split(',') for item in initial]

print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['MILK', 'BREAD', 'BISCUIT'], ['BREAD', 'MILK', 'BISCUIT', 'CORNFLAKES']]
```